# Scanner issue, input information not working

Tags: java, input, output

the question, I look at the code millions of times, may be I just can't see the simple answer but why at the point of Author name and Author Surname, system print out like this:

```
Enter author Name: Enter author Surname:
```

and it should be like this...

```
Enter author Name: 
Enter author Surname:
```

and if I input information in system remember only Author first name and I can't put information for surname.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BookTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {    

        Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);

        Book bookIn = new Book();

        System.out.print("Enter book title: ");
        bookIn.setTitleBook(scan.nextLine());



        System.out.print("Enter author Name: ");
        bookIn.setFirstName(scan.nextLine());

        System.out.print("Enter author Surname: ");
        bookIn.setSecondName(scan.nextLine());

        System.out.print("Enter author Nationality: ");
        bookIn.setNationality(scan.nextLine());




        System.out.print("Enter book price: ");
        bookIn.setPriceBook(scan.nextDouble());

        System.out.print("Enter book ISBN: ");
        bookIn.setIsbn(scan.nextInt());




        System.out.println("Title: " +bookIn.getTitleBook());
        System.out.println("Author: "+ bookIn.getFirstName()+ " " + bookIn.getSecondName());
        System.out.println("Price: "+bookIn.getPriceBook());
        System.out.println("ISNB Number: "+bookIn.getIsbn());
        System.out.println("Aurhor Nationality: " + bookIn.getNationality());



    }
}
```

Book Class

```
public class Book {

    private double priceBook;
    private int isbn;
    private String titleBook;
    private String firstName;
    private String secondName;
    private String nationality;


    public void setTitleBook(String titleBook){
        this.titleBook = titleBook;
    }
    public String getTitleBook(){
        return titleBook;
    }


    public void setPriceBook(double priceBook) {
        this.priceBook = priceBook;
    }
    public double getPriceBook() {
        return priceBook;
    }


    public void setIsbn(int isbn) {
        this.isbn = isbn;
    }
    public int getIsbn() {
        return isbn;
    }



    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }




    public void setSecondName(String secondName) {
        this.secondName = secondName;
    }
    public String getSecondName() {
        return secondName;
    }


    public void setNationality(String nationality) {
        this.nationality = nationality;
    }
    public String getNationality() {
        return nationality;
    }



}
```

Comment: I think you probably want to have that information in the same Book object. Instead of creating six different Book objects, create just one and call the setter methods on that object.

Comment: Sorry, could you explain a bit more about this?

Comment: Sure. You have a Book object with 6 fields. Now in your test code, you are creating six different objects and setting one field in each of them. But what you probably need to do is set all six fields in the same object.

Comment: Is it like this? I edit my code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the scanner to the next line after reading the ISBN.  When using `Scanner.nextInt` the input only reads the number and not the new line character created when you press enter.  Calling `Scanner.nextLine` after `Scanner.nextInt` reads the new line character and clears the buffer.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BookTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {    

        Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);

        Book title = new Book();
        Book price = new Book();
        Book isbn = new Book();
        Book fName = new Book();
        Book sName = new Book();
        Book nation = new Book();

        System.out.print("Enter book title: ");
        title.setTitleBook(scan.nextLine());

        System.out.print("Enter book price: ");
        price.setPriceBook(scan.nextDouble());

        System.out.print("Enter book ISBN: ");
        isbn.setIsbn(scan.nextInt());

        scan.nextLine(); //NOTICE CHANGE HERE
        //System.out.println(); THIS WAS REMOVED


        System.out.print("Enter author Name: ");
        fName.setFirstName(scan.nextLine());

        System.out.print("Enter author Surname: ");
        sName.setSecondName(scan.nextLine());

        System.out.print("Enter author Nationality: ");
        nation.setNationality(scan.nextLine());


    System.out.println("Title: " +title.getTitleBook());
    System.out.println("Price: "+price.getPriceBook());
    System.out.println("ISNB Number: "+isbn.getIsbn());

    System.out.println("Author: "+ fName.getFirstName() + sName.getSecondName());
    System.out.println("Aurhor Nationality: " + nation.getNationality());



    }
}
```

Comment: Is it like this ( it works)?

Scanner scaner = new Scanner (System.in);
  
  
  System.out.print("Enter author Name: ");
  fName.setFirstName(scaner.nextLine());
  
  System.out.print("Enter author Surname: ");
  sName.setSecondName(scaner.nextLine());
  
  System.out.print("Enter author Nationality: ");
  nation.setNationality(scaner.nextLine());

Comment: It should work.  I'm not sure exactly what your asking though in this comment.  Look for the comments that say "NOTICE CHANGE HERE" within my posted solution.

Comment: If possible, could you explain why.... it doesn't work with one scanner ( it actually only bug at one stage and I not really understand why)?